# Update using JS, Google Spread Sheet as a anonymous user without providing credentials

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

The sheet is sharable, and publicly editable, I know it can be edited without credentials using API. But I couldn't find examples for the same.

```
 gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
```

But I don't want to provide any key, etc. I just need to update the sheet anonymously. How to initiate the edit, without logging in or providing credentails.

Answer (score 0):

All Google APIs require's some sort of credentials in order to provide authorization, even if if you are trying to access public data, creating an [API key](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#api-key) will allow you to modify the sheet as you mentioned and you will identify yourself through the API key.

Now there is also this [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36755576#comment3) that explains that you need authentication in order to modify a `Public Editable Spreadsheet`.

You could as well use a service account to perform the changes if the sheet is publicly available, there is a great guide in this [article](https://isd-soft.com/tech_blog/accessing-google-apis-using-service-account-node-js/).

Comment: Yes, but I want it to edit as an anonymous user, providing credentials means I would be editing with my credentials. I have seen an 3rd party API, which lets you edit document, which are publicly shared as editable, so I think its possible, just can't find the docs.

Comment: That could be done with the last step I mentioned by using a service account, you make changes with the service account, as you still need to provide credentials somehow, the service account does that for you.

Comment: You may as well check the Issuetracker that confirms that you DO need some sort of authentication to make changes to a public spreadsheet